# Stop Multiple Tasks at once

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am starting multiple tasks with a parallel foreach loop.

Now I want on click of a stop button all task to be stopped. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
tasks2 = new List<Task>();            

Parallel.ForEach<RssToProcess>(RssFeeds, rssFeed =>
    tasks2.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        string urlss = rssFeed.RssUrl;
        nourl += urlss + System.Environment.NewLine;

        RssReader rs = new RssReader();
        rs.FeedsourceLoaded += new EventHandler(rs_FeedsourceLoaded);
        rs.ItemAdded += new EventHandler(rs_ItemAdded);
        rs.AllItemAdded += new EventHandler(rs_AllItemAdded);
        rs.RssReaderrssitemsCountgeta += new EventHandler(rs_RssReaderrssitemsCountgeta);
        rs.RdfMode = true;

        RssFeed f = rs.Retrieve(rssFeed.RssUrl);
     })));
```

Comment: Why do you use threads(Parallel.ForEach) to create another threads(Task.Factory.StartNew). A simple foreach loop isn't enough?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be passing a CancellationToken:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx

Create a CancellationToken:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;
```

And pass it to your tasks:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
           ... Do Work ...
        }, token);
```

When you want to cancel, call

```
tokenSource.Cancel();
```

However, note that task cancellation is cooperative.
Within your tasks, you will need to use

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // To Abort immediately.

 ... OR ...

if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // Exit your task manually.
}
```

Comment: seems like the if check isn't needed, at least given the name of the method 'ThrowIfCancellationRequested' ?

Comment: If you need to support cancellation happening before the ForEach has finished, you can pass in the cancellation token via setting the property of a ParallelOptions instance.